# How can i use java web service client for multiple endpoints?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, netbeans-7

I have a web service built on Netbeans in Java where I want to send requests to different endpoints.
Ie, there is a certain method I want my web service to call, but each time from a different endpoint.
Is there a way to do this?
Or alternatively, can I insert into an existing WSDL file, another endpoint and then load the file into a Web service client and then decide within the Web service client to which endpoint I send the method call?

Comment: What is your need? A frontal Apache for load balancing before your servers can do the job ?

Comment: @user2378231 I believe his need is to differ between several servers with the same wsdl file

Comment: if both endpoint has the same implementation (i hope), you can check this kind of architecure: http://www.membrane-soa.org/service-proxy-doc/3.5/soap-loadbalancing.htm